Kafka compressed topic weird behaviour
We've been using Kafka for many years, starting from version 0.8, which had some issues that were resolved in later versions. Currently, we are using version 2.X, and we have many topics (100+), partitions, parallel consumers, and producers. The throughput has been optimal for many years. All our systems are physical; there is nothing virtual or in the cloud.
However, we recently encountered a strange problem that we had never observed before. We created a topic that receives many messages with a larger size than usual (averaging between 100 and 500KB). To improve transfer efficiency, we decided to use Gzip compression by creating the topic with the --config compression.type=gzip parameter. Typically, our topics either have no compression (because they are very small) or we manage compression directly from the producers and consumers (AKA producer compression).
The issue is that message production times grew uncontrollably, reaching up to 450ms per message of 100-500KB. Initially, I thought that compression was affecting the CPU of the producers or consumers, but they were barely utilizing 10% (none of the cores exceeded 20%, and the machines were running only that producer). On the Kafka brokers side, the situation was similar. None of them exceeded 30% CPU usage. Other metrics, such as memory, I/O operations, and bandwidth, didn't seem to be affected either. Interestingly, the production times for messages of similar size (slightly smaller) remained at 3ms. That’s 150 times faster than the compressed messages. So we can assure the brokers were still working smoothly.
At that point, we gave up and created another topic without compression. Now the production times are down to 3ms. I suspect either it’s a bug that specifically affects topics with “server” compression, or the ingestion or replication flow for these types of topics uses a different process stream that we might be overloading in some way.
Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior? Are there any known bugs that could exhibit this behavior?
Thanks!
